# can someone explain why I failed this audit? thank you

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9427902

I read the question carefully:

> **Question**:
>   From which line java compiler starts checking the coding lines
>
> In what order java compiler checks the lines of the program. whether starting from the first line ? or starting from the main method?

It's not a particularly interesting question, it's pretty fundamental, and it's not extremely well-written, but it is well-defined and has a simple answer. And it has been up-voted once already.

The answer which I must audit reads:

> compiler will start from the first line.
>
> answered Aug 20 at 12:41
>   M.Prabhu

So, not the greatest answer I've ever seen on stackoverflow, not full of explanation of *why* it does this, or compare / contrast with other languages, or code examples to easily verify this, or reference to some standard or some such.

But it directly answers the question, correctly, and it is comparable to the question at least in depth and quality.

I clicked to upvote this answer. Instead, I am told that I failed the audit, and shown that it has been down-voted (and ultimately deleted).

Another reviewer has commented:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. –  Sufian Aug 20 at 13:18

This simply isn't true, the answer does provide an answer to the question.

I think this wasn't an appropriate audit question, it was far from clear-cut how it should have been handled. It seems like possibly the most appropriate answer to the question, maybe with a little better formatting / grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was flagged as VLQ which pushed it into the LQP queue where it gathered sufficient (recommend) delete votes to be removed which made the post a potential audit candidate where any positive action (eg: upvoting it) would be deemed a failure.

I wouldn't have upvoted it (but can see why) and I wouldn't have voted to delete it in the other review either (but can see why). This is one of those obscure cases where difference of opinion in reviewing across queues has ended up - umm, shall we say, not exactly desirable?

Anyway, moving forward, this should no longer be an issue, and any consequences of failing the audit have been reversed.